# Using SignalR for targeted updates rather than broadcasts

Tags: signalr

Sorry for the general nature of this question. It is less about how to use SignalR, but more about how to use it well. I think I have the "how" solved, but I'm new to SignalR and I am worried I might be using it in a way that might not scale well.

Our system will be processing applications and we have multiple clients with multiple users using the same system. The back-end processing required for each application can be time consuming (measured in minutes, hours, and even days, but usually just minutes), so I am using SignalR to keep the each user updated about the progress of the application they are actively looking at.

Application 123 does not need to know about updates to application 124, so I am creating a SignalR Group for each application (IE one named "App-123" and another named "App-124"). When one of the back end process for 123 completes, SignalR will trigger a message to the "App-123" group.

We currently expect to see a few dozen applications being monitored at a time, so I'm not worried it keeping up now. I'm more worried about the future. Do I need worry about unused groups getting backlogged? Will there be an issue when we have hundreds or even a thousand applications being monitored? Do you have any warnings or wisdom to offer?

Thanks.

P.S. We will also be using SignalR in other (more traditional) ways, but I'm not concerned there.

Comment: Just to get the concepts right: an application can have multiple clients monitoring it. Is that right?

Comment: An application can have multiple users viewing it, but all those users will be with the same client.  I don't want users from one client to see any information from another client. SignalR will help maintain that client boundary, but it will ultimately be enforced by the API.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR does not have much built in for pub / sub. I created this wrapper around SignalR that makes it alot more event driven. It also has a constaint API so that you easily can control which user gets which events

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki